# Git error when attempting to push across SMB share

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, smb, cifs

I am developing code on a Ubuntu VM, and have a Windows Repository on a common shared server my team uses.

Git is installed on the Ubuntu machine and not on Windows, currently.

I was receiving errors when trying to do a "git init" in Ubuntu on the Windows share folder so I created the folder in Ubuntu using "git init", then copied it to the folder that housed the project on the Windows server.

In Ubuntu, I did a git clone /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server..../Repos/demo_trunk/.     successfully

I could make edits fine, commit fine but when I try to push OR pull my changes by way of something like "git push origin master", I get an error saying my share, /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server..../Repos/demo_trunk/. does not appear to be a git repository and could not read from remote repository. It also says, Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have already checked to ensure that when I do "git remote -v" that the smb server folder (/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server..../Repos/demo_trunk/.) exists.

Also, after making the change on my Ubuntu machine and running git status, the output says my branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit, which seems to indicate it at least knows something changed in comparison to what is out on the Windows server.

I am at a complete loss and have Googled my head off trying to find a solution. It appears that it could be a permissions issue, but nothing has seemed to be specifically what I need.

Any advice would be most welcome.

**5/26/2021**

1. Installed cifs
2. Reinitialized the repo THROUGH the Ubuntu VM using the mounted drive created by cifs.
3. Made edit, checked in edit on Ubuntu VM.
4. Ran "git remote -v"

   origin /mnt/cifs/demo/.   (fetch)

   origin /mnt/cifs/demo/.   (push)
5. Ran "git status"

   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
6. Ran "git push origin master'

   Counting objects: 4, done.

   Delta Compression using up to 2 threads.

   Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.

   error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory

   To /mnt/cifs/demo/.

   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)

   error: failed to push some refs to '/mnt/cifs/demo/.'
7. Ran git push origin/master

   fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository

   fatal: 'Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights

   and the repository exists.
8. I also ran a git reset --hard command (don't remember syntax)

   This successfully "reverted" back to what was out on the Windows share drive.

Comment: I would not use GVFS for Git operations.  it provides some basic operations, but I don't think it provides a full set of POSIX behavior.  Try using the Linux `mount.cifs` instead.

Comment: @bk2204 I'll try this in the morning. Do you think that would cause the issues I'm seeing?

Comment: I think it likely will.  I've seen other people have problems with Git and GVFS in other situations, although I don't recall if it was SMB or SFTP.

Comment: @bk2204 added updates above. Let me know your thoughts! Thank you so much.

Comment: You don't have the proper permissions to create files on the remote repo, since you can't create a directory.

Comment: @bk2204 Is that still the case even though I can create folders on the Ubuntu cifs mnt(i.e. navigate to the mnt/cifs/demo/ folder and mkdir rmdir)? I'm able to see the folder get created/deleted on the windows side.

Comment: Well, you're unable to create the temporary directory, so it's either a permissions problem or some other type of problem, and my _guess_ is that it's permissions.

Comment: This solutions worked. Part of the issue was I need to run git push as sudo and cifs was necessary as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when mounting a cifs-share from a fritzbox.

I looked a bit under the hood, running `strace -f git push` and found that git was looking at the correct directory. But it failed to do something with the `HEAD` file, getting a `Stale file handle`-error as response.

```
...
stat64("/cifs/repo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/cifs/repo/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/cifs/repo/HEAD", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ESTALE (Stale file handle)
...
```

As written [here](https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=176154#p1228236), adding the mount-option `noserverino` fixed my problem.